# asp.net core 2.2 response cache not work on browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.2

The response cache works well in Postman But cache does not work in other browsers and "Cache-Control" in browser is " public, max-age=60" . 
And every time refresh browser the action method is called .
my Api Code :

```
[HttpGet]
    [ResponseCache(Duration =60)]

    public IActionResult GetAllCustomer()
        {           
        Request.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("X-Total-Custumer", _h_Plus_SportsContext.Customer.Count().ToString());

        return new ObjectResult(_customerService.GetAllCustomer())
        {
            StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK
        };
    }
```

Comment: Please check if you haven't enabled the Disable cache in the developer toolbar of the browser you are using.

Comment: @Jb_Dda, show your Startup class configuration code.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more context, but Chrome and possible other browser are sending by default `Cache-control` header with a value of 0 (this happens even if Chrome Dev Tools has Disable cache unchecked):

[image: Cache control 0]

A workaround is to follow a link to your link to be tested or use Back button as indicated [here](https://superuser.com/questions/313131/how-do-i-stop-chrome-sending-cache-control-max-age-0-when-i-hit-enter).

Comment: Can you please take a look at the question I posted?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72755972/netcore-responsecache-does-not-work-for-some-routes